# How to ignore SSL validation errors from angular client when using SignalR (.Net Core)?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, websocket, signalr

I am using a angular app, which is connecting to a SignalR server (.Net 5). When I try to connect to server from client I get following error.

[image]

Is there any way to ignore SSL errors from angular client? I am using "@microsoft/signalr: 5.0.7 package

Is there something similar to ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback in Angular SignalR client package?

Below is my angular code

```
var options: IHttpConnectionOptions = {
  accessTokenFactory: () => { return this.accessToken }
};

this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(hubUrl, options).build();
```

Comment: Could you pls show us which tutorial you followed so that it may help us locate the issue. By the way, I used to create a SignalR server with an react frontend project, my connection url is like `https://localhost:44336/chatHub` and it doesn't appear any ssl error. I mean you may need to provide more details on your code or the error message as the screenshot indicated that `see inner exception`. Debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Pls allow me show some of my code snippet first to help you check if there's somewhere missed configuration.

My signalr.service.ts, and I referred to [this blog](https://mfcallahan.blog/2020/11/05/how-to-implement-signalr-in-a-net-core-angular-web-application/) to create my angular project (from using command to create project to modify `providers` in `app.module.ts` file and run the project to check if succeed to connect).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalrService {
  private hubConnection : signalR.HubConnection;

  constructor() { 
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("https://localhost:44336/chatHub").build();
  }

  public startConnection = () =>{
    this.hubConnection.start()
      .then(()=>console.log("Connection start"))
      .catch(err =>{
        console.log("error while starting :" + err);
    });
  };
}
```

And I followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.1) to create my asp.net core web app for signalr, but pls note here, as your case is frontend + backend, we need to set cors policy in startup.cs and this will make the `ConfigureService` method look like this :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy",
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowCredentials();
                                  });
            });
            services.AddSignalR();
        }
```

And then when we start both of the project, we can see connection established successfully.

[image]